# JdbcTemplate mapper null value

Tags: java, jdbctemplate, lombok

POJO with `Lombak`:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter @Setter
public class Order {
    private int Id;
    private int OrderId;
    private String Status;
}
```

Using `JdbcTemplate` I select the record:

```
String sql = "SELECT Id, OrderId, Stataus" +
                "ORDER BY t.Sort";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{IDU}, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Order .class));
```

Since the some of the OrderId is `null`, I get this error:

```
Failed to convert property value of type 'null' to required type 'int' for property 'OrderId';
```

Can I solve this problem without using `custom mapper`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int` is a primitive in Java and it cannot be `null`.

The `BeanPropertyRowMapper` could not convert `null` to `int` so it threw exception.

To fix this you can either:

- Change `int` field to `Integer` and get `null` after mapping
- [`setPrimitivesDefaultedForNullValue`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/BeanPropertyRowMapper.html#setPrimitivesDefaultedForNullValue-boolean-) to `true` on the `BeanPropertyRowMapper`

But remember that

> if you use the values from the generated bean to update the database the primitive value will have been set to the primitive's default value instead of `null`.

Answer (score 4):

Simply fetch it into `Integer` instead of `int`.